# Google таблицы. Как получить строки, у которых отличается значение указанного столбца и не получать те, где это значение повторяется?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть таблица типа такой:
[image: Данные]

Нужно получить такую:
[image: Результат]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Меню "Данные" - "Очистка данных" - "Удалить повторы". Убедиться, что выбраны оба столбца и установлена галка "Данные со строкой заголовка". Нажать кнопку "Удалить повторы".
Либо использовать функцию [`=UNIQUE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10522653?hl=ru)

Для выбора нужных столбцов можно использовать следующее выражение:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY(A2:C7;"select A,C";-1))
```

где `A2:C7` - диапазон с данными. `select A,C` выбирает из диапазона только столбцы A и C, пропуская B.

Или вообще чисто с `QUERY`:

```
=QUERY(A2:C7;"select A,min(B),C group by A,C label A 'Наименование', min(B) 'Другое',C 'Цена'";-1)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Меня больше интересует вариант с =UNIQUE(), поскольку хочу использовать полученный результат в дальнейших разработках, а удаление данных - нет, потому как эти данные как бы не лишние и удалять их нельзя. Но не могу понять как получить весь диапазон данных (все поля) применив =UNIQUE() только к 2-м полям?

Comment: @QwerTy дополнил ответ

Comment: Все, сделал что хотел. Спасибо огромное! QUERY рулит, конечно )